# std::function is not derived from 'std::reference_wrapper<_Tp>'

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

Trying to unit test private callback method of a class. Callback is registered using function which I can mock and then by using EXPECT_CALL and SaveArg I can capture callback function to std::function test member and call it for testing purposes. That works fine.

The problem starts when callback method itself takes std::function as a parameter.

**Production code:**

Private callback method I am trying to test:

```
void
MyClass::callbackMethod(const Callback callback)
```

Callback which is taken as parameter to callbackMethod:

```
typedef std::function< void(void) > Callback;
```

Public function in which callback is bound:

```
void
MyClass::initialize(const Callback callback)
{
      m_SomeClass->registerCallback(std::bind(&MyClass::callbackMethod, this, callback));
}
```

**Test code:**

Tets class memeber to which I am trying to save callback argument from a register function:

```
std::function< void(const Callback callback) > m_Callback;
```

What should happen here:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*m_SomeClassMock, registerCallback(_))
         .WillOnce(SaveArg< 0 >(&m_Callback));
```

**Gives following error:**

```
...
/usr/include/c++/6/functional:1999:2: note: candidate: template<class _Functor> std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>& std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator=(std::reference_wrapper<_Functor>) [with _Functor = _Functor; _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {std::function<void(void)>}]
  operator=(reference_wrapper<_Functor> __f) noexcept
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/functional:1999:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from .../ext-cppunit-google-mock-dev/5/workspace/usr/include/gmock/gmock.h:65:0,
                 from .../SomeClassMock.hpp:15,
                 from .../MyTest.cpp:16:
.../gmock/gmock-more-actions.h:172:12: note:   'std::function<void(void)>' is not derived from 'std::reference_wrapper<_Tp>'
   *pointer = ::testing::get<k>(args);
   ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Not sure what is causing this error by maybe the fact that in last line of error probably there should be:

```
std::function<void(std::function<void(void)>)>
```

is giving some clue?

Comment: Can you condense your description down to a [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem?  At the moment, there's far too much missing information (and extraneous information - do we really need `SomeType1` and `SomeType2`, or does the error manifest with one or both removed?).

Comment: A function can't be named `register`: that's a keyword.

Comment: Removed SomeTypes - they seems to be not relevant. Problem appears when Callback parameter is added to MyClass::callbackMethod.

Comment: Please, show `registerCallback()`. In tested code it takes  one param, in mocked version 3 - `(_, _, _)` -  do you have some default ones?

Comment: It takes one parameter, corrected.